# Creating table from tennis statistics in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new here so I have some pretty basic questions. I have lots of tennis statistics and I am trying to create some new ones in Microsoft Access. So, I have table1 with all players head 2 heads and scores. (column 1: player 1, column 2: player 2, column 3: tournament, column 4: result, column 4: date played). In table 2, I have 2 columns, column 1: tournament column 2: surface.

Now with these 2 tables, I want to create a new one with an extra column showing the total games played between the 2 players. The tricky part for me is how to add all the games when in column 4 I have for example 6-4 6-3 6-2 also trickier when its a tie break it shows 7-6(4). (I don't want to add the 4 here)

The objective would be to get an average of total games played between 2 players or when I select one particular player, filtering by surface, date and/or tournament.

Thank you in advance for anyone who can help me.

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would really help convey what you are trying to do.

Comment: At first glance I would say that your DB structure is not designed properly and that you will never suceed to compute what you want with SQL queries. Either you change your structure (which will need an initial load with your data redsigned), or you let your tables like this and do what you want entirely with VBA code. I can help you with both solutions but as requested above, you have to post a data sample

Comment: @ThomasG hi if you could help me that would be great is there anyway of sending it to your personal email as i dont want to publicly post it

Comment: @Alexander nope sorry, we stay here. Nobody asks you to show off real data, only a small and fake part of it